# Prevent XML file in media directory to be cached

Tags: xml, cache, full-page-cache, media

We are generating a custom XML and stored in the media directory to be accessed by URL. La full URL of the XML have this structure:

**https://[maindomain.com]/media/googleshopping/googleshopping4-1.xml**

The files are generated constantly. However, we detected that sometimes, the XML is not updated. For example, right now, if we enter the URL, we see this date at the end of the file:

[image]

But if I put a change in the URL, format example adding a random param:

**https://[maindomain.com]/media/googleshopping/googleshopping4-1.xml?test=885624**

Here we see the correct date:

[image]

We tried clearing the browser cache and opening the URL in incognito mode but continued seeing the past date. We suppose the file is cached. Is some way to prevent this specific file from being cached?

Answer (score 1):

You must have a server cache for Static files meaning CSS, js, and XML for your website. that why this reason this issue happens.

If you are using Cdn or a cache system like Cloudflare then you have to add `media/googleshopping/googleshopping4-1.xml` to the non-cache file to the respective system.

Comment: Yes, I forget to mention that the site is in Magento Cloud using Fastly. The solution was indeed to add the XML to the Custom VCL to bypass the Fastly cache: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/cdn/custom-vcl-snippets/fastly-vcl-bypass-to-origin.html